# Remove Closely Matching String from All Entries in a mySQL Database using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress mysql database that I only have phpMyAdmin access to.  A few thousand entries (post_content in the wp_post) have a string like the examples below within the post_content that I need to remove (but not anything else in the post_content).

As you can see, each string is slightly different, but have similarities. I've dabbled with wildcards (% and _) but can't seem to get it quite right through phpMyAdmin's find/replace tool.

```
<!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->
<!-- xqmbbHiYB5 --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->
<!-- Po1o6IUJby --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->
<!-- xqmbbHiYB5 --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->
```

etc...

Comment: please show us what u have done.. and we will help you to fix..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a query like this. It tests only the fix string at start, middle and the end of the string. Also it checks the lenght.

```
SELECT 
  val
, REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('<!-- ',val),60),'') after_replace
FROM testtable
WHERE
    LOCATE('<!-- ',val) > 0
AND
     SUBSTRING(val,15+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),12) = ' --><!-- /* '
AND
     SUBSTRING(val,53+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),7) = ' */ -->'
; 


UPDATE testtable
  set val =  REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('<!-- ',val),60),'') 
WHERE
    LOCATE('<!-- ',val) > 0
AND
     SUBSTRING(val,15+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),12) = ' --><!-- /* '
AND
     SUBSTRING(val,53+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),7) = ' */ -->'
;
```

**sample**

**test data**

```
mysql> select * from testtable;
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | val                                                                                     |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | <!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->                            |
|  2 |      asdfasefasdf<!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->asdfasdfas |
|  3 | 12345<!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->67890                  |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**SELECT Sample**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->   val
    -> , REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('<!-- ',val),60),'') after_replace
    -> FROM testtable
    -> WHERE
    ->     LOCATE('<!-- ',val) > 0
    -> AND
    ->      SUBSTRING(val,15+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),12) = ' --><!-- /* '
    -> AND
    ->      SUBSTRING(val,53+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),7) = ' */ -->'
    -> ;
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| val                                                                                     | after_replace               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| <!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->                            |                             |
|      asdfasefasdf<!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->asdfasdfas |      asdfasefasdfasdfasdfas |
| 12345<!-- ZUJ7vPmaFn --><!-- /* 1uqjsQSyWVhmOHAEVa1i62html */ -->67890                  | 1234567890                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**the update**

```
mysql> UPDATE testtable
    ->   set val =  REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING(val,LOCATE('<!-- ',val),60),'')
    -> WHERE
    ->     LOCATE('<!-- ',val) > 0
    -> AND
    ->      SUBSTRING(val,15+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),12) = ' --><!-- /* '
    -> AND
    ->      SUBSTRING(val,53+LOCATE('<!-- ',val),7) = ' */ -->'
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from testtable;
+----+-----------------------------+
| id | val                         |
+----+-----------------------------+
|  1 |                             |
|  2 |      asdfasefasdfasdfasdfas |
|  3 | 1234567890                  |
+----+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Sorry to be slow (sql is not my forte), but is val in your sample above my field name in the table I want to update?